# Django: Using two different databases, with two different structures, for models

Tags: python, django, database

I have a legacy database, that is used by several legacy applications.  I'm building a new Django app that uses this legacy database, but I want to also start building its own database, that will have a different structure than the old one. As an example, the old database might have a `person` table like

```
id | first_name | last_name
```

and the new database has a `person` table like

```
id | whole_name
```

Because the old database will eventually not be used for this app, I want to build the models so that "switching" is as easy as possible down the road.

Essentially, I need to be able to read data from the old database, and using a `transform` method (assume I already wrote it), fill out a model based on the new database.  Then, when writing data, it gets written to both databases, using a `detransform` method to convert to the old structure.

Thus, I need the following.

- Any read operation (like `query` or `all`) grabs data from the old database, transforms it to the new database structure, and populates the model instance
- Any write operation (like `save`) writes the data to both databases: as-is for the new one, and the result of detransform for the old one
- I want this to be as transparent as possible to the models, so that later on, when we only need the new database, as little code as possible needs to be changed

My current thinking is to write models for all the old tables, normally.  Then write an abstract base class for the new models, that overrides the `save` method and defines a custom manager (which reimplements the `get_query_set` method, for example).  Then all the models for the new tables inherit from this base class. When we're ready to switch to only using the new DB, we simply make the base class a stub.

Is this the right way to do this? Are there better methods? I tried looking at database routers, but they seem to only work when the table structures are the same.

Comment: Do you have to support backward compatibility with old database, after switching to new db (continue writing to it, or fetching data) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use few databases for one app.
I would suggest you define both models and redefine save method for model to old db and create method for model to new db ( it allows you to create and save new model  instance to new db while performing save to old db ).
Later you just have to remove code (+ minor refactoring of places where old model used).